# Perl 6: Getting the name of function from inside it

Tags: function, introspection, raku

In Perl 6, how can I get name of the function/subroutine from within its body, at runtime?

For example,

```
sub foo {
    say "My name is: " ~  <WHAT-API-HERE??> ;
}
...
foo();
```

The above code should print:

```
My name is: foo
```

I've looked in places like [MOP](https://docs.perl6.org/language/mop#index-entry-MOP), [FAQ](https://docs.perl6.org/language/faq), and [Functions](https://docs.perl6.org/language/functions).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
sub foo { say &?ROUTINE.name }
foo
```

displays:

```
foo
```

See [the `&$ROUTINE` doc](https://docs.perl6.org/language/variables#&?ROUTINE).

Comment: Thanks, I was simply looking in the wrong places like MOP, FAQ, Functions.

Comment: @Harry Always share at least mention of your research effort when asking a question. I just edited your comment into your question to help make your previous research effort more obvious. I'm guessing that not realizing your previous research effort might be why someone (not me) downvoted you. Anyway, hope this is helpful! I'm really glad you asked this question and glad that raiph shared the answer.

Comment: @Harry yw. Imo your search choices (MOP, FAQ etc.) were perfectly reasonable whereas there's no way you could be expected to know to look at a page on variables for the answer. More generally the documentation is much better than it was but still has a very long way to go. Also note that, at the time of writing this comment, by far the best place for getting answers to questions about Perl 6 relatively quickly isn't SO but rather the various friendly IRC channels for Perl 6, most notably [Freenode #perl6](https://kiwiirc.com/client/irc.freenode.net/perl6).

Comment: @jjmerelo Thanks for improving the doc and editing my answer to catch up. :)